# How can I align every word from this list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

I have a list of lists in a file:

```
[ [ 'aaaaa', 'bbb','ccccccccc' ], [ 'aaaaa', 'bbbbbb','cccccc' ], [ 'aaa', 'bbb','ccccccccc' ] ]
```

```
aaaaa bbb ccccccccc
aaaaa bbbbbb cccccc
aaa bbb ccccccccc
```

I use it for some analysis but because of the lengths of the words, it is hard to read, I want to format it to look something like this:

```
aaaaa  bbb     ccccccccc
aaaaa  bbbbbb  cccccc
aaa    bbb     ccccccccc
```

Maybe with some generous spaces between columns.

I guess I can use `.format` function but I tried and I found no solution.

I can only use Python 2.7.

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Why can you not use Python 3?

Comment: I can't because the project implies that I use only python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with Python2.7:

```
lst = [ [ 'aaaaa', 'bbb','ccccccccc' ], [ 'aaaaa', 'bbbbbb','cccccc' ], [ 'aaa', 'bbb','ccccccccc' ] ]

widths = [max(len(j) for j in i) for i in zip(*lst)]
s = ''.join('{{:<{}}}'.format(w+2) for w in widths)

for v in lst:
    print(s.format(*v))
```

Prints each column aligned to max width of string inside this column + 2 extra characters:

```
aaaaa  bbb     ccccccccc  
aaaaa  bbbbbb  cccccc     
aaa    bbb     ccccccccc
```

Comment: I had a solution which is too similar to yours to warrant posting as a separate answer, but just a question: I had an `s` after the width in the format which you don't have - i.e. `"{{:<{}s}}".format(width)` - do you expect this to make any difference?

Comment: Thank you so much, just tried your solution and it works!

Comment: Just tried it without the `s` and it seems to make no difference at all.

Comment: @alaniwi According the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) `'s' - String format. This is the default type for strings and may be omitted.` So it makes no difference if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [ [ 'aaaaa', 'bbb','ccccccccc' ], [ 'aaaaa', 'bbbbbb','cccccc' ], [ 'aaa', 'bbb','ccccccccc' ] ]

# max_lengths = [max(len(y) for y in x) for x in zip(*my_list)]
# Can do above and get max lengths for each a, b, c etc but let us just get one global max for a neater solution

max_length = max(max(inner_list) for inner_list in my_list)

with open(target, "w") as writer:
   for inner_list in my_list:
       l_justed = [x.ljust(max_length) for x in inner_list)
       writer.writeline("    ".join(l_justed))
```

ljust adds spaces at the end to make the string length as specified value