# Random spacing when using /t in a string in Python 3.8.x

Tags: python

Second last line has the "problem".

This is the code:

```
cities = []
prompt = "Please enter the names of any five cities that you have visited."
prompt += "\nWe will compile them into a list for you"
num = 1
flag = True

while num <= 5 and flag:
    city = input(f"City {num}: ")
    if city.lower() == "quit":
        break
    else:
        cities.append(city)
        num += 1

print()

num = 0
place = ""
comp = ""
print("So you have visited the following cities:")
for place in cities:
    num += 1
    comp += f"{num}. {place}\t"
print(comp)
```

It is supposed to ask for 5 inputs and then number them and put them all in one sentence, as a string, then print that string.

It "works", there are no errors, but the space created in the result due to \t in the second last line always seems to vary. Sometimes there is no space at all, and sometimes there are two spaces. Same code, run over and over in command prompt, but different results every time in the behavior of \t.

It works perfectly if I replace the \t with four spaces.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Python will print a tab character when you ask it to, how it will be interpreted depends on your terminal. Usually, it goes to the next multiple-of-some-number-of-characters column.

Comment: Can you post example output? Does it seem to vary based on the number of characters in the place name?

Comment: a tab is expected to be 8 positions by default. Every character takes up a space of that position. So if you have a word of 5 chars, then there will be only 3 spaces. If the word has more than 8 characters, then it shifts the tab to the next. \t is dynamic. Instead try using format

Comment: Consider a shorter, running example. You could give us a prepopulated `cities` list and the last 4 lines of code to demonstrate.

Comment: Can you try to apply this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023871/how-can-i-align-every-word-from-this-list/63024106#63024106

Comment: On a computer terminal, tab stops are a set of predefined locations on a line, usually spaced every 8 characters. The `\t` says move to the next tab stop which could be from 1 to 8 characters away. You could see how this lines up by doing `print("\t".join("x"*9))` just above your odd print to  show where those tab stops are.

Comment: @Temp14, just curious - why are we using flag?

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur Yeah, flag is redundant. I am new to the language, learning from a book. The current section is teaching how to use flags in while loops and the code was supposed to be WAY simpler, utilizing the flag and break only, but I wanted to add my own touch and it became something entirely different...

Comment: @Temp14, its great that you added your own touch. That's the way we learn. :)

Comment: @tdelaney I ran the code, and it clarified how the \t thing works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab just moves to the next tab stop. A tab does *not* equal four spaces. This is used to line up columns when printing multiple lines.

```
print("test\ttest")
print("test12\ttest")
print("test12345\ttest")
```

Output

```
test    test
test12  test
test12345       test
```

Comment: Ah OK. The book I am learning from did not say exactly what \t did so I assumed it was for spacing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to try to change your format statement to be something like this.

```
for place in cities:
    num += 1
    comp += f"{num}. {place:15}" 
    #your string length will always be left justified to 15 chars 
print(comp)
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know that you could justify things at all. I am still quite new to programming.